# How do I get inside a room with locked door in inform 7?

Tags: inform7

I am new to inform 7 and I am very simply trying to have a locked door in a room and unlock it, which I have done, but now I need to be able to enter a room on the other side of this door.
This is the part I need to fix:

The Castle Door is a door in Castle Entrance. It leads to Treasure Room. It is lockable and locked. The
Bronze key unlocks Castle Door.

The Error message says it doesn't understand the 'leads' to part of it. So how do I get inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Leads to" isn't valid Inform syntax. Door locations are defined just like rooms so that the door is placed in the middle of the rooms it connects. See [Writing with Inform ch. 3.12](http://inform7.com/book/WI_3_12.html).

```
The Castle Door is a door. It is lockable and locked. 
The Castle Door is south of Castle Entrance and north of Treasure Room.
```

If you want to use inside/outside instead of compass directions:

```
The Castle Door is inside of Castle Entrance and outside of Treasure Room.
```